# Count number of right truncated rows in bcp import

Tags: bash, bcp

I am trying count the no. of truncation errors that happens when bcp import is performed. I have tried a simple logic in which I redirect the output of bcp and then grep `right truncation` in that file. Following is the code snippet :

```
bcp Test..Table in datafile.txt -f format_file -m 0 -S server -T > error_file.txt
error_count=`cat error_file.txt | grep -c ".*right truncation.*" `
```

The problem is that `grep` takes too much time when there are many rows and moreover it takes more time even when there is no right truncation error. Is there a better way for this?
I am using `bcp` utility in windows under `cygwin` and importing it into `MS SQL server 2008`.

Comment: If you just want to grep `right truncation`, avoid the asterisks that will make it perform slowlier. Just `grep -c "right truncation" error_file.txt` should make it.

Comment: Yes but will this bring a considerable increase in performance? I mean is there a method to increment a variable on right truncation while I am importing the data. Here I am processing the whole data file again.

Comment: There won't be a big increase of performance. You can check it adding `time` in front of your commands. Regarding the second question, I would suggest you to check the `bcp` options.

Comment: I think this can be speed up a little bit using `fgrep -c 'right truncation' error_file.txt`. The ".*" in RE ".*right truncation.*" ha no real relevance. You do not have to add them. Program `fgrep` perform a little bit bitter as it checks for fixed texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched on `bcp` and found the `-e` switch which directly writes any errors in an error log file and greping them directly from that log gives a significant performance boost.

Here is the output of bcp in command :

```
Starting copy...
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 1000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 2000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 3000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 4000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 5000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 6000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 7000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 8000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 9000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 10000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 11000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 12000
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation

12406 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1351   Average : (9182.8 rows per sec.)

[INFO BCP IN: data2.txt] Import failed for 1 rows out of 12407 rows, Total 0.0%.

Fri Sep 20 01:24:39 CDT 2013

[INFO BCP IN: data2.txt] Total time elapsed 0 days 0 hour 0 minutes 2 seconds
```

Here is the error log output :

```
#@ Row 12407, Column 1: String data, right truncation @#
The Bulk Copy Program (BCP) is a command-line utility
```

So modifying the code to grep error log file instead of the whole output of bcp in we can get a very good performance boost:

```
bcp Test..Table in datafile.txt -f format_file -m 0 -S server -T -e error_file.txt
error_count=`fgrep -c "right truncation" error_file.txt `
```

*fedorqui, TrueY and pgl thanks for suggestions.*

Answer (score 1):

The biggest speedup you are going to get here is to pipe everything together. ie, instead of your command, you would have:

```
error_count=$(bcp Test..Table in datafile.txt-f format_file -m 0 -S server -T | fgrep -c "right truncation")
```

(The above includes the already-suggested change to remove ".*" from your regex, and use `fgrep`.)

This avoids writing something to disk and then reading it all again to search for your `right truncation`.

Last minor point: I think the command you included in your post is missing a space (`datafile.txt-f`)?

Comment: +1, for pipelining, but this still processes the whole output which I want to avoid.